# Equivalence of models of computation

Tags: turing-machines, lambda-calculus, computation-theory

I'm seeking explanation on how one could prove that models of computation are equivalent. I have been reading books on the subject except that equivalence proves are omitted. I have a basic idea about what it means for two models of computation to be equivalent (the automata view: if they accept the same languages). Are there other ways of thinking about equivalence? If you could help me understand how to prove that the Turing-machine model is equivalent to the lambda-calculus, that would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

To prove an model `A` is equivalent to model `B` you need to show that:

1. Model `A` is not stronger then model `B`
2. Model `B` is not stronger then model `A`

To show model X is not stronger then model Y one must prove:

> For every machine from X, there exists a machine from Y such that L(M_X)
>   = L(M_Y)

[where M_X and M_Y are different machines from each model respectively]

A common well known proves are:

- DFA is equivalent to NFA
- NFA is equivalent to NFA with epsilon moves
- [Multi tape turing machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine_equivalents#Multi-tape_Turing_machines) is equivalent to one tape turing machine

More info on this subject can be read under [Turing machine equivalents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine_equivalents)

Also note, the claim: `the automata view: if they accept the same languages` is not true.

You don't need to show the *same automata* accept the same language in both models.

**You need to show that for each automata in A there is an automata in B such that L(M_A) = L(M_B) and vise versa**